# SWRevealViewController No StoryBoard and Toggle with UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to use the SWRevealViewController without a storyboard and with a UIButton. My project has two UIViewControllers with nib's. The main one is called ViewController and the other is called MenuViewController.

In my ViewController I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MenuViewController *menuView;

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:menuView frontViewController:self];

    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}

- (IBAction)toggleMenu:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Toggling menu");
    SWRevealViewController *revealController = self.revealViewController;
    [revealController rightRevealToggleAnimated:YES];
}
```

The toggle menu button prints "Toggling Menu" as expected but doesn't reveal the menu controller. I know this isn't the conventional way of using the SWRevealViewController but does someone have any ideas how to get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in viewDidLoad()

```
self.revealViewController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: That did not work. I also added some delegate methods and they did not get called either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one with some modifications. It helped in my case.

```
- (IBAction)toggleMenu:(id)sender{
    [self.btn addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods I use to set up the two (left and right) view controllers for SWRevealViewController. Just call them in `viewDidLoad`.

```
-(void) initSlideMenu
{
    SWRevealViewController * menuViewController =  (SWRevealViewController *)self.revealViewController;

    if (menuViewController)
    {
        [_menuButton setTarget:self.revealViewController];
        [_menuButton setAction:@selector(revealToggle:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
-(void) initRightMenu
{
    SWRevealViewController * rightViewController = (SWRevealViewController *)self.revealViewController;
    if (rightViewController)
    {
        rightViewController.rightViewRevealOverdraw =0.0f;
        [_notificationButton setTarget:self.revealViewController];
        [_notificationButton setAction:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```